# Contact form showing error on submit

Tags: php, html

I humbly seek your help on an issue I encountered after creating a contact form for a website. On clicking submit, all I get is an "Error!" message. I believe the issue is related to the php scripts I used. The validation script works well though. I will paste the php script and form html here so you can help look into it. Your help will be well appreciated! Thanks in advance!

```
<?php
    $owner_email='name@domain.com';
    //SMTP server settings  
    $host = '';
    $port = '465';//"587";
    $username = '';
    $password = '';

    $subject='A message from your site visitor ';
    $user_email='';    
    $message_body='';
    $message_type='html';

    $max_file_size=50;//MB 
    $file_types='/(doc|docx|txt|pdf|zip|rar)$/';
    $error_text='something goes wrong';
    $error_text_filesize='File size must be less than';
    $error_text_filetype='Failed to upload file. This file type is not allowed. Accepted files types: doc, docx, txt, pdf, zip, rar.';

    $private_recaptcha_key='6LeZwukSAAAAACmqrbLmdpvdhC68NLB1c9EA5vzU'; //localhost


    $use_recaptcha=isset( $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"]) and isset($_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);
    $use_smtp=($host=='' or $username=='' or $password=='');
    $max_file_size*=1048576;

    if($owner_email==''){
        die('Attention, recipient e-mail is not set! Please define "owner_email" variable in the MailHanlder.php file.');
    }

    if(preg_match('/^(127\.|192\.168\.)/',$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])){
        die('Attention, contact form will not work locally! Please upload your template to a live hosting server.');
    }

    if($use_recaptcha){
        require_once('recaptchalib.php');
        $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($private_recaptcha_key,$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],$_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],$_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);
        if (!$resp->is_valid){
            die ('wrong captcha');
        }
    }

    if(isset($_POST['name']) and $_POST['name'] != ''){$message_body .= '<p>Visitor: ' . $_POST['name'] . '</p>' . "\n" . '<br>' . "\n"; $subject.=$_POST['name'];}
    if(isset($_POST['title']) and $_POST['title'] != ''){$message_body .= '<p>Course Title: ' . $_POST['title'] . '</p>' . "\n" . '<br>' . "\n";}
    if(isset($_POST['organisation']) and $_POST['organisation'] != ''){$message_body .= '<p>Organisation: ' . $_POST['organisation'] . '</p>' . "\n" . '<br>' . "\n";}
    if(isset($_POST['work']) and $_POST['work'] != ''){$message_body .= '<p>Work Description: ' . $_POST['work'] . '</p>' . "\n" . '<br>' . "\n";}
    if(isset($_POST['address']) and $_POST['address'] != ''){$message_body .= '<p>Address: ' . $_POST['address'] . '</p>' . "\n" . '<br>' . "\n";}
    if(isset($_POST['city']) and $_POST['city'] != ''){$message_body .= '<p>City: ' . $_POST['city'] . '</p>' . "\n" . '<br>' . "\n";}
    if(isset($_POST['states']) and $_POST['states'] != ''){$message_body .= '<p>State: ' . $_POST['states'] . '</p>' . "\n" . '<br>' . "\n";}
    if(isset($_POST['email']) and $_POST['email'] != ''){$message_body .= '<p>Email Address: ' . $_POST['email'] . '</p>' . "\n" . '<br>' . "\n"; $user_email=$_POST['email'];} 
    if(isset($_POST['phone']) and $_POST['phone'] != ''){$message_body .= '<p>Phone Number: ' . $_POST['phone'] . '</p>' . "\n" . '<br>' . "\n";}   
    if(isset($_POST['fax']) and $_POST['fax'] != ''){$message_body .= '<p>Fax Number: ' . $_POST['fax'] . '</p>' . "\n" . '<br>' . "\n";}
    if(isset($_POST['enquiry']) and $_POST['enquiry'] != ''){$message_body .= '<p>Any Enquiry?: ' . $_POST['enquiry'] . '</p>' . "\n" . '<br>' . "\n";}
    if(isset($_POST['message']) and $_POST['message'] != ''){$message_body .= '<p>Message: ' . $_POST['message'] . '</p>' . "\n";}  
    if(isset($_POST['stripHTML']) and $_POST['stripHTML']=='true'){$message_body = strip_tags($message_body);$message_type='text';}

try{
    include "libmail.php";
    $m= new Mail("utf-8");
    $m->From($user_email);
    $m->To($owner_email);
    $m->Subject($subject);
    $m->Body($message_body,$message_type);
    //$m->log_on(true);

    if(isset($_FILES['attachment'])){
        if($_FILES['attachment']['size']>$max_file_size){
            $error_text=$error_text_filesize . ' ' . $max_file_size . 'bytes';
            die($error_text);           
        }else{          
            if(preg_match($file_types,$_FILES['attachment']['name'])){
                $m->Attach($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'],$_FILES['attachment']['name'],'','attachment');
            }else{
                $error_text=$error_text_filetype;
                die($error_text);               
            }
        }       
    }
    if(!$use_smtp){
        $m->smtp_on( $host, $username, $password, $port);
    }

    if($m->Send()){
        die('success');
    }   

}catch(Exception $mail){
    die($mail);
}   
?>




HTML-----


<form id="contact-form" action='MailHandler.php'>
                                <div class="contact-form-loader"></div>
                                <fieldset>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="grid_2">
                                            <label class="name">
                                                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name:" value=""
                                                       data-constraints="@Required @JustLetters"/>
                                                <span class="empty-message">*This field is required.</span>
                                                <span class="error-message">*This is not a valid name.</span>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="grid_2">
                                            <label class="email">
                                                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail:" value=""
                                                       data-constraints="@Required @Email"/>
                                                <span class="empty-message">*This field is required.</span>
                                                <span class="error-message">*This is not a valid email.</span>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="grid_2">
                                            <label class="phone">
                                                <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone:" value=""
                                                       data-constraints="@JustNumbers"/>
                                                <span class="empty-message">*This field is required.</span>
                                                <span class="error-message">*This is not a valid phone.</span>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <label class="message">
                                        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message:"
                                                  data-constraints='@Required @Length(min=20,max=999999)'></textarea>
                                        <span class="empty-message">*This field is required.</span>
                                        <span class="error-message">*The message is too short.</span>
                                    </label>
                                    <div class="btn-wrap">
                                        <a class="btn_3" href="#" data-type="reset">clear</a>
                                        <a class="btn_3" href="#" data-type="submit">send</a>
                                    </div>
                                </fieldset>
                                <div class="modal fade response-message">
                                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                                        <div class="modal-content">
                                            <div class="modal-header">
                                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                                                        aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="modal-body">
                                                You message has been sent! We will be in touch soon.
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

Comment: Does it literally just say "Error!" or does it have a full error message? Check your error logs too.

Comment: Why is this tagged with javascript?

Comment: It displays only "error!". I tried a different email address to see if the issue is email related but still the same. You can check it out at: http://culminateconsulting.com/contacts/

Comment: @Lee That was probably a mistake. Can you help?

Comment: checked the url you provided. It was submitted successfully.

Comment: Thank you all, i fixed it! The problem was I failed to link the 'MailHandler.php' script in my Javascript properly, it was pointing to a script outside the folder. All the forms are working properly now.